# Unable to compile the Virtual Network Device and start VMware

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

VMware worked OK before I updated to Ubuntu 12.04. But now when I try to run VMware Player, it says that it needs to compile and load into the running kernel, using VMware Kernel Model Updater. It successfully compiles the following: Virtual Machine Monitor, VMware Blocking Filesystem, Virtual Machine Communications Interface and the VMCI Sockets. But it is unable to compile the Virtual Network Device and therefore won't start the VMware Services. Is this a know issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please add the specific error it tells you into your question

Answer (score 6):

`VMware` Player Compile Issues on Ubuntu 12.04 solution:

Create the symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/vmware /etc/rc.d/init.d
```

Then run the following command to install all `vmware` services:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Start `VMware`

```
vmplayer
```

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you install the player correctly.

1. Download VMware Player from [here](http://www.vmware.com/go/downloadplayer/)

   - I noticed it downloads as a text file via chrome.
   - Ensure you rename the file extension to ".bundle"
2. Install the player

   ```
   sudo sh ./VMware-Player-4.0.2-591240.x86_64.bundle
   ```
3. Download the package from [here](http://slackblogs.blogspot.de/2012/01/vmware-workstation-802-and-linux-kernel.html)
4. Extract it package and run the patch

   ```
   sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
   ```

That should work.

@redshark: Thanks for the link!

For VMware player version 4.0.3 see [answer by **@dbrewer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/131037) on [How do I install VMware Player 4.0.3 (and patch the installer to work on my 12.04 system)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130937)

Comment: **Update for VMware player version 4.0.3**
[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130937/vmware-player-4-0-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

With regards to 4.0.3, just an additional detail (I am unable to post it into the 4.0.3 thread, so hence posting it here)

when i ran the patch script or `vmwareplayer` it would bail out with this error

```
sh: 1: /etc/rc.d/init.d/vmware: not found
Unable to stop services
```

so what i did was simply create a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d /etc/rc.d/init.d
```

(i.e. a link to `/etc/init.d` inside `/etc/rc.d/`

as a result i now had links to both `vmware` and `vmware-USBArbitrator` in `/etc/rc.d/`

after this the error disappeared and I was able to compile the modules

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that worked for a friend of mine: http://slackblogs.blogspot.de/2012/01/vmware-workstation-802-and-linux-kernel.html
For me it didn't work and I used the beta, which works just nicely on ubuntu 12.04 :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, if this is *your* blog, the link could be considered self-promotion. Please see http://askubuntu.com/faq#promotion

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a apt-get install patch first so that the patch-modules_3.2.0.sh script run. After that I could use VMWare again. I am using an 12.04 upgraded from 11.10 xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Got a working set of 5 instructions and a patch from:

http://dakotux.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/install-vmware-player-on-ubuntu-1204/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, if this is *your* blog, the link could be considered self-promotion. Please see http://askubuntu.com/faq#promotion