# How to fix "Unable to start services" in VMware Player 4.0.3. on Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit

Tags: 12.04, vmware, 32-bit

I just updated to Ubuntu 12.04 and installed the lastest VMware (4.0.3).
When it starts it shows "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into running kernel".

After compiling it shows "Unable to start services. See log file /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-17200.log for details". The log is:

```
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=17200 version=8.0.3 build=build-703057 option=Release
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: The process is 32-bit.
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Host is Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2012-05-07T12:43:24.785-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-05-07T12:43:24.785-03:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2012-05-07T12:43:24.785-03:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-05-07T12:43:24.785-03:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2012-05-07T12:43:24.786-03:00| vthread-3| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-17200.log
2012-05-07T12:43:24.901-03:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf query interface initialized
2012-05-07T12:43:24.922-03:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf library initialized
2012-05-07T12:43:24.948-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:24.952-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:24.952-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-05-07T12:43:24.952-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-05-07T12:43:24.952-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:24.954-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:24.962-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:24.988-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:24.988-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:24.990-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:24.997-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:25.024-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.043-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.046-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.049-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.052-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.056-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.070-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.072-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.075-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.077-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.079-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.081-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:25.081-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-05-07T12:43:25.081-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.081-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:25.083-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:25.090-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:25.111-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.128-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.130-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.133-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.135-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.138-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.140-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:25.140-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-05-07T12:43:25.140-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.140-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:25.142-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:25.150-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:25.175-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.207-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.211-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.213-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.216-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.218-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.449-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.450-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:25.452-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:25.462-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:25.491-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.491-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmmon.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.491-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.
2012-05-07T12:43:25.501-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:29.241-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmmon from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc.
2012-05-07T12:43:29.242-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc/vmmon.ko
2012-05-07T12:43:30.300-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:30.300-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:30.302-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:30.309-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:30.333-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:30.333-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmnet.
2012-05-07T12:43:30.333-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmnet module.
2012-05-07T12:43:30.340-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:32.352-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmnet!
2012-05-07T12:43:32.357-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:32.357-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:32.359-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:32.367-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:32.393-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:32.393-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmblock.
2012-05-07T12:43:32.393-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmblock module.
2012-05-07T12:43:32.402-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:39.651-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmblock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc.
2012-05-07T12:43:39.651-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc/vmblock.ko
2012-05-07T12:43:40.798-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:40.798-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:40.801-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:40.821-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:40.847-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:40.848-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-05-07T12:43:40.848-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-05-07T12:43:40.857-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:43.301-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmci from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc.
2012-05-07T12:43:43.301-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc/vmci.ko
2012-05-07T12:43:44.466-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae.
2012-05-07T12:43:44.466-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae
2012-05-07T12:43:44.468-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:44.476-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:44.503-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-24-generic-pae is valid.
2012-05-07T12:43:44.503-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-05-07T12:43:44.503-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-05-07T12:43:44.514-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:45.089-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vsock.
2012-05-07T12:43:45.089-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vsock module.
2012-05-07T12:43:45.098-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-05-07T12:43:48.932-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vsock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc.
2012-05-07T12:43:48.933-03:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/misc/vsock.ko
```

Is there a fix for this?

**Related question** (for 64bits, didn't work for me - the script runs successfully, but nothing changes): [How do I install VMware Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130937/vmware-player-4-0-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit)

Comment: Having the same problem as well on 12.04, 11.10 works flawlessly with VMWare Player.  Would love to see a resolution on this as I never could find one. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download this [patch](http://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2025997-86343/vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz)

Edit the script for 4.0.3

```
gedit patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```

On line 8, change the version number to version of VMware Player that you're using.

from

```
plreqver=4.0.2
```

to

```
plreqver=4.0.3
```

or

```
plreqver=[x.x.x]
```

Run the script.

```
sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```

Comment: I did but I got the following error patch-modules_3.2.0.sh: 27: [: player4.0.3: unexpected operator patch-modules_3.2.0.sh: 28: [: player4.0.3: unexpected operator Sorry, this script is only for VMWare WorkStation 8.0.2 or VMWare Player 4.0.2. Exiting

Comment: This is the answer on the linked related question. The script runs, but nothing changes.

Comment: @TomBrito are there any errors when you run the `patch-modules_3.2.0.sh` script? I actually did `sudo -` and from the root shell ran `./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh`. Slightly different than my answer but maybe important.

Comment: @TomBrito Make sure you **DON'T** run the script with **sh patch-modules_3.2.0.sh** but you do it with **sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh** Also use the **vmware-installer -l** command to check what VMware Player version you have installed and change plreqvar accordingly in patch-modules_3.2.0.sh (i.e. you may have 4.0.2 or 4.0.3)

Comment: Just one thing that I would like to add. Between the constant freezing and lack of kernel support with VMware I decided to try VirtualBox. I regret not trying it earlier. It is rock solid, well supported on Ubuntu and it actually feels faster. After 12 years of being a loyal VMware fan, I've finally jumped ship and it doesn't look like I'm going back any time soon.

Comment: As of July 2012, the most recent version of VMplayer (4.0.4) still requried this patch for me on kernel 3.2. Thus, `plreqver=4.0.3` should be changed to `plreqver=4.0.4`.

Comment: When a new kernel is installed however you might get this message: sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh 
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/.patched found. You have already patched your sources. Exiting. Simply remove the file and try again.

Comment: Very good. Worked flawlessly.

Comment: I'd like to confirm that this works even on 8.0.3

Comment: @RichardAyotte where should i put this patch in order to run it