# Vmware installation on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: kernel, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VMware Player 4.0.3. on Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133285/vmware-player-4-0-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-32-bit)

I installed VMware 8.04 on Ubuntu 10.04. When I run the VMware workstation, it shows the message like

> "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel".

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: Refer http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58594-Problem-updating-VMware-Kernel-Module-after-upgrade

Comment: @aking1012 This isn't a dupe of that question, because that question is about an Ubuntu 12.04 specific problem that is fixed by a patch specific to kernel version 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

That message usually contains an OK or Next button that will proceed to build the modules.

If not, open a terminal and type:

> vmware-modconfig --console --install-all