# VMware Player 4.04 on Ubuntu 12.04 will not compile

Tags: 12.04, kernel, vmware

I installed VMware-Player-4.0.4-744019.i386.bundle onto Ubuntu 11.10.
This worked fine.
I then upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04
The upgrade appeared to be successful.

I then tried to start VMware Player and I got a popup
"VMware Kernel Module Updater"
I accept the process (click Install)

The updater process runs, the output of which is:

```
Stopping VMWare Services
[green tick]    Virtual Machine Monitor
[RED exclamation mark]    Virtual Network Device
[green tick]    VMware Blocking Filesystem
[green tick]    Virtual Machine Communication Interface
[green tick]    VMCI Sockets
```

An error dialog box pops up, with a red exclamation mark and the text:

```
Unable to start services
See log file /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-11912.log
```

Looking in the log file, it seems that these are the complaints:

```
2012-07-11T15:35:19.829Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h 

2012-07-11T15:35:19.829Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h 

2012-07-11T15:35:49.683Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmnet!
```

I tried the patch for 4.0.3 and it did not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

This is the full log file:

```
2012-07-11T15:35:18.618Z| vthread-3| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=11912 version=8.0.4 build=build-744019 option=Release
2012-07-11T15:35:18.618Z| vthread-3| I120: The process is 32-bit.
2012-07-11T15:35:18.618Z| vthread-3| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2012-07-11T15:35:18.618Z| vthread-3| I120: Host is Linux 3.2.0-26-generic Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2012-07-11T15:35:18.616Z| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-07-11T15:35:18.616Z| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2012-07-11T15:35:18.616Z| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-07-11T15:35:18.616Z| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-07-11T15:35:18.617Z| vthread-3| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2012-07-11T15:35:18.618Z| vthread-3| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-11912.log
2012-07-11T15:35:19.054Z| vthread-3| I120: modconf query interface initialized
2012-07-11T15:35:19.056Z| vthread-3| I120: modconf library initialized
2012-07-11T15:35:19.158Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.168Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:19.168Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-07-11T15:35:19.168Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.168Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:19.175Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.201Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.291Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.292Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:19.296Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.326Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.417Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.480Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.489Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.498Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.507Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.517Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.566Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.575Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.584Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.593Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.602Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.606Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:19.606Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-07-11T15:35:19.606Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.606Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:19.611Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.635Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.741Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.787Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.796Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.805Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.814Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.824Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.829Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:19.829Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-07-11T15:35:19.829Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-07-11T15:35:19.829Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:19.834Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.857Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:19.945Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:35:25.503Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:25.514Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:25.523Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:25.533Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:25.542Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:26.338Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:26.338Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:26.343Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:26.368Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:26.455Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:35:26.455Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmmon.
2012-07-11T15:35:26.455Z| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.
2012-07-11T15:35:26.484Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:35.469Z| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmmon from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc.
2012-07-11T15:35:35.470Z| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
2012-07-11T15:35:39.713Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:39.713Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:39.719Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:39.753Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:39.845Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:35:39.845Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmnet.
2012-07-11T15:35:39.846Z| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmnet module.
2012-07-11T15:35:39.913Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:49.683Z| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmnet!
2012-07-11T15:35:49.704Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:35:49.705Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:35:49.729Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:49.874Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:49.961Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:35:49.961Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmblock.
2012-07-11T15:35:49.961Z| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmblock module.
2012-07-11T15:35:50.159Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-07-11T15:35:59.283Z| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmblock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc.
2012-07-11T15:35:59.284Z| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc/vmblock.ko
2012-07-11T15:36:04.318Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:36:04.319Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:36:04.324Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:36:04.344Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:36:04.427Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:36:04.427Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-07-11T15:36:04.428Z| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-07-11T15:36:04.456Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-07-11T15:36:15.728Z| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmci from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc.
2012-07-11T15:36:15.730Z| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc/vmci.ko
2012-07-11T15:36:20.349Z| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-26-generic.
2012-07-11T15:36:20.350Z| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic
2012-07-11T15:36:20.355Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:36:20.378Z| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-07-11T15:36:20.464Z| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-26-generic is valid.
2012-07-11T15:36:20.464Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-07-11T15:36:20.464Z| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-07-11T15:36:20.514Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-07-11T15:36:22.732Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module vsock.
2012-07-11T15:36:22.732Z| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vsock module.
2012-07-11T15:36:22.783Z| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-07-11T15:36:33.825Z| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vsock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc.
2012-07-11T15:36:33.826Z| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/misc/vsock.ko
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow [the procedure detailed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130937/vmware-player-4-0-3-on-ubuntu-12-04), but just change the line `plreqver=4.0.2` to `plreqver=4.0.4`. This worked for me. ;-)